# Incorrect Convert Data from String to Float in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have an excel file that has decimal value with text formatted like

`'123.32323` in Column `Value` which tells Microsoft Excel to convert to number in Excel..

I want to import this value to `DT_R8` as `float` value into SSIS Project. I have created Derived Column with `(DT_R8)[Value]` Casting of column and try also for converting with Data Transformation but the result I have  the values change into `12332323` It doesn't look for `.` in there.

My Local Excel ID is Indonesian Which the comma is `,` and separator `.` and I have change it in `English (United States)` but it stills the same.

How I can convert this text type as `Float` in SSIS ?

Comment: In Excel- Select a cell and go to to format cells and change the datatype to Number and make sure the decimal place is not zero. Now try to manually enter a float value in that cell and see it is showing the decimal values correctly.

Comment: Did you tried using the IMEX=1 in your excel connection manager[Appended to the Connection string]? Which will bring the data as its. After that you can type cast to DT_R8 using SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually going slightly crazy about this myself.  If the data in the csv is encased in quotes, when SSIS imports csv file it includes the quotes in the output of the rows so you actually have to remove the end quotes yourself. Otherwise you are literally trying to cast the quotes and the number to a float.  Passing the output of the CSV import to a derived column control will work for you.

In the expression field of the derived column -> (DT_R4)REPLACE([Column Name],"\"","")

This removes the quotes then cast the value out to a float.

Comment: This actually has been corrected in SSIS 2014 and I think 2012 as well. You can specify a text qualifier, like a ".